# Rewriting groupby, arrange and mutate with if-else from R to Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, code-translation

I am trying to rewrite my code from R to Python. I am having a hard time rewriting some of my code involving `group_by`, `arrange` and `mutate`. I have tried `transform` and `apply` in Python but have had no success.

In R my code looks like the following:

```
S1 = S1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(Date) %>% mutate(New_Factor = ifelse(r_type == 5, (1+(Price/Last_Price)), Old_Factor/lag(Old_Factor)))
```

however, I am having a very difficult time rewriting this code in Python. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
s1['New_Factor'] = s1.groupby(['ID'],group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: (1+(Price/Last_Price)) if g.type == 5 else (Old_Factor/lag_value))
```

where `lag_value` is defined as:

```
lag_value = s1['Old_Factor'].shift(1)
```

the error I get is:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I am also wondering if `.tranform()` is a better way of going about this? Please let me know - as I will probably be doing this quite a bit with my code conversion.

Comment: Is there any problem with your attempt?

Comment: Apologies. updated with error.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, group_by, arrange, mutate, if_else, lag
>>> 
>>> S1 = tibble(
...   ID=[1,1,2,2],
...   Date=["1/1/2021", "1/1/1997", "3/3/2020", "12/1/2020"],
...   Price=[3.23, 1.23, 5.33, 9.88],
...   Last_Price=[1.22,2.21,3.21,2.11],
...   Old_Factor=[3,4,5,6],
...   r_type=[5,5,6,6]
... )
>>> 
>>> S1 >> group_by(f.ID) >> arrange(f.Date) >> mutate(
...     New_Factor=if_else(
...         f.r_type==5, 
...         1+f.Price/f.Last_Price, 
...         f.Old_Factor/lag(f.Old_Factor)
...     )
... )
       ID       Date     Price  Last_Price  Old_Factor  r_type  New_Factor
  <int64>   <object> <float64>   <float64>     <int64> <int64>   <float64>
0       1   1/1/1997      1.23        2.21           4       5    1.556561
1       1   1/1/2021      3.23        1.22           3       5    3.647541
2       2  12/1/2020      9.88        2.11           6       6         NaN
3       2   3/3/2020      5.33        3.21           5       6    0.833333

[Groups: ID (n=2)]
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.